# How to add validation to my activity onCreate to validate input EditText text,or number data to SQLite in Android app

Tags: android, validation, android-edittext

I am trying to make a survey app with Android Studio that store data to SQLite database. I did it so, but my app shows has stop warning that because I've input an invalid entry so I want to add validation to input EditText from myActivity's onCreate, if it is possible for my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_buat_biodata);

    dbHelper = new com.example.try1.DataHelper(this);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    text3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    text4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    text5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    ton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    ton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("insert into biodata(no, nama, tgl, jk, alamat) values('"+
                    text1.getText().toString()+"','"+
                    text2.getText().toString()+"','"+
                    text3.getText().toString()+"','"+
                    text4.getText().toString()+"','"+
                    text5.getText().toString()+"')");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            MainActivity.ma.RefreshList();
            finish();
        }
    });
    ton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling SQLite methods (db.execSQL), you should write some validating methods.
these methods will be combination of some if else conditioned. First you should check if condition for all fields have proper data and filled with text or not like below code.

```
email = tie_emailId_SignUp.getText().toString();
password = tie_password_SignUp.getText().toString();
confirmPassword = tie_confirmPassword_SignUp.getText().toString();

if (!email.isEmpty() && isvalidateEmail(email)) {
    if (!password.isEmpty()) {
        if (!confirmPassword.isEmpty() && confirmPassword.equals(password)) {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Something like this, according to your situation and then save the data in to your database.